# If two oppositely charged rods are placed near small pieces of paper why do they both attract the paper?

Tags: electrostatics, statics

Take two oppositely charged rods, place them near small pieces of paper, and both rods will attract the paper. Why do both negatively and positively charged rods attract the paper in the same way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Rania. The pieces of paper are not initially charged. They either have a charge induced on them by the rod, or they are polarised by the electric field of the rod. This works the same way whether the rod is positive or negative. For example a positive rod would induce a negative charge on the paper, and the opposite charges attract. Likewise a negative rod would induce a positive charge on the paper, and again the opposite charges attract.

Comment: @JohnRennie Won't a positive rod induce a negative charge on the part of the paper closest to it, rather than the entire piece of paper?

Comment: @zucculent if the paper is on a conducting surface charge can flow on or off of the paper  and it can end up with a net charge. The surface doesn't have to as good a conductor as a metal. It just needs a resistivity that isn't effctively infinite.